# How to access Google Drive document contents through https from a Rails app hosted on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, https, google-drive-api

I have a Rails app (https://github.com/ddelruss/loops) which I have hosted on Heroku. It uses a Rails form to collect the user's Google id, password, and document id, which it uses to log in to Google drive, download the document contents, and render as a D3 visualization. All that works fine - test if you like (and trust the current security):

http://young-eyrie-4632.herokuapp.com/

You can use the publicly available demo document key:
0AtOGnLq8Mf_ydGtmMmI5UjhEUmlqQ0d6UHFVaWN2TWc

None of the user information is stored, as I want to keep the site as secure as possible. The flaw is that the site is currently accessed at http, which I understand to mean that the user credentials are sent from the web form to Heroku/Rails unencrypted.

So, I want to access the app through https, which Heroku supports through ssl piggybacking. And indeed the site loads with https:// and will render the visualization page. The problem is that the Google doc does not return any results. The login succeeds, no application error (according to heroku logs)...just with an empty result.

What can I do to get my app working through https, including getting results from the Google drive document? Note that I don't need both - if https works I'm fine disabling http access.

Thank you,

Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your app with the demo document and the Hierarchy option with both http and https and from looking at the HTML, it appears that the content is present in both cases, but not displayed in the case of https. That is, I believe Google is returning the document properly.

I didn't do a complete comparison of the HTML generated in the two cases, but after a quick glance, it appears that the http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js /script node is not present in the case of https access as it is in the http case.

Hope this helps.

Pete

4/25/13 Update: Looking at my Console output on Chrome, I see the following error:

> [blocked] The page at https://young-eyrie-4632.herokuapp.com/loops/nodes ran insecure content from http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js.

and I confirmed that this script does not appear under Chrome's "Sources" tab, so I gather it's not getting loaded in the https case.  I don't know if you can change this to an https reference or whether you're going to have to add it to your repository so that Rails loads it at startup.  That still leaves the reference to http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js.  I can't figure out where that's coming from.

Comment: I was able to remove the http reference to d3 by using the d3_rails gem. That works in my localhost, which in encouraging. Unfortunately when I push to Heroku the pages break (even http), unable to find d3. I'm looking at it now - please post if you have any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up simply (ha!) putting the d3.js code into my rails vendor/assets/javascripts folder, precompiling as per Heroku deployment instructions, and removing the script tag from the html. Everything is updated in github for anyone interested. Since this answer got me going again, full bounty! Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad you got it working, Damien, and thanks for the full bounty. That was generous and much appreciated. I'm curious as to what led you to precompiling, however. Did you see a problem in the output of the heroku push where, if I understand it, the assets are compiled as part of slug compilation?

Comment: It's possible that I don't need to precompile, and the real change was including the vendor/assets/javascripts/*.js into my asset build. I did precompiling because I thought it would result in faster performance but perhaps that is misguided - I'm still very new to Rails. Thanks!